# How can I get URL information following "#" in Koa

Tags: koa

I have a URL that in the browser shows like this `https://localhost:3000/location#valueIwant=1234`.

I am trying to get access to the valueIwant value but all of the items I try `ctx.request.path`, `ctx.request.href`, etc but all seem to not have the values after #. How do I parse this part of the url.

Also this is coming from a redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Everything after the `#` is not sent to the server. The purpose of the fragment is to create a link to a specific subsection of a page.

If you want to send specific parameters to the server, the right way to do it is to use the query part (everything after `?`), not the fragment part. This is by design.

Comment: Can you just expand a little on this, for example mine is automatically in the url and I see no JS or anything running to add it. How is it being added, and does this mean I can still grab it client side just not serverside?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got a fragment, maybe somebody created a link with a fragment and you clicked on it? You can grab the information on the client-side with the `document.location` object.

Comment: I will tell you it was coming back from a redirection to an auth0 server. But that was what was confusing me too.

Comment: Well, there is an OAuth2 flow that uses fragments, but the purpose of using fragments is to *prevent* tokens from being sent to a server. This is for security reasons.